# Dynamically bind controls to the grid view in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to bind controls to the grid view but i want to do it dynamically.As an example i just want to enter students marks to text box to adjacent  subjects??

thinks students are in row's and subjects are in columns and it similar to matrix in mathematics . but some times no of students and no of subjects are vary.

Therefore i have to bind it dynamically 
CAN ANY ONE HELP ME WITH THIS

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowDataBound event. You can add any control there.

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cells[0].Controls.Add(cb);
```

Comment: http://damithonnet.blogspot.com/2010/03/dynamically-bind-any-of-checkbox.html Following link would be help more about control binding to asp gridview